# Which matcher should I use in restassured to match number like 1.0

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm using restassured and org.hamcrest.Matchers. I have the following response from my api

```
{
  "entity" : {
    "value" : 1.0
  }
}
```

in my tests I have the following code

```
given()
  .headers(createHeaders())
.when()
  .get(url)
  .prettyPeek()
.then()
  .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
  .body("entity.value", is(1.0));
```

Which is failing with message

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path entity.value doesn't match.
Expected: is <1.0>
  Actual: 1.0
```

What Matcher should I use in this code?
On DTO level it is

```
BigDecimal value;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rest Assured: java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path body doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803954/rest-assured-java-lang-assertionerror-json-path-body-doesnt-match)

Comment: Did you try body("entity.value", is("1.0")); | This should possibly work, the response returned by rest assured is a as a string but the value you compare against is int and so the error

Comment: No. It's not a string. On the DTO it is BigDecimal I it helps

Comment: Ahh, How about this - body("entity.value", is(new BigDecimal(1.0))

Comment: No. But if you know the reason, then you can find right answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815071/confusion-over-rest-assured-floating-point-comparisons]

Comment: @alekz Can you try this, body("entity.value", is(1.0f))

Comment: @alekz Try this one http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#equalTo(T)

Comment: Here is the link to documentation: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#note-on-floats-and-doubles explaining this feature